# SQL Migration of Databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-migration

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a test database that I've modified to have new foreign keys and columns etc.

I was wondering what is the best way to map all of the changes to my live db?

Do I have to run a drop and create script individually on each table?

I tried to right click -> tasks -> generate database scripts -> but this gets a lot of errors when I run this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to compare databases and apply changes from one to the other (in your case test to production) is to use SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools).

With this tool you can easyly compare tow databases, source and target, see the necessary scripts to update each object of the target database, so that it's exactly like the source database, and run all, or only the selected scripts to the target database.

You can also generate an update script, or a dac pac.

Please, see this for more information:

- [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/data/tools.aspx).
- [How to: Use Schema Compare to Compare Different Database Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx)
- [SSDT Schema Compare (youtube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKSsbWnFMD8)

Comment: Thanks I'll do some research on these links

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that simple compare & sync does not utilize the version control repository when performing the compare and generating the DDL script. For that reason the version control repository does not act as the single source of truth.

Another problem that simple compare and sync runs into is, that because the information is stored in the ALM, CMS, or version control repository, which is external to the compare & sync tool, it compares the entire database and shows the differences, generating relevant and irrelevant deployment scripts.

Most critically, simple compare and sync does not ensure the deployment script handles conflicts and merges them.

Database enforced change management on the other hand, combines enforcement of version control processes on the database objects with generation of the deployment script when required, based on the version control repository and the structure of the environment at that time.

This approach uses “build and deploy on-demand,” meaning the deploy script is built (generated) when needed, not as part of development. This allows for efficient handling of conflicts, merges, and out-of-process changes.

Have a look here for more information:

[DevOps for Database](http://www2.dbmaestro.com/l/11742/2014-05-04/vx6t1?LightBox_Resource_Name=DevOps%20for%20Database)